# AWS Lambda with Node.JS in production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use Node.js in AWS Lambda in production.
The question is how to make this reliable.

For me, reliability means:

1. Retrying some parts of code - this exists from-the-box in AWS Lambda
2. Exception notification - I tried Airbrake, but it does not work in AWS Lambda - `process.on('uncaughtException')` does not work
3. Possibility to know if something is down and even exception notification does not work - in a usual app, I have the healthcheck endpoint.

So how can I implement 2 and 3 points?

Comment: Regarding point 2, why doesn't your approach work?  The other points might be too broad for SO.

Comment: @E_net4I saw the question on their forum that this method stopped working so I suppose that they override it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is using a `SQS queue` as a `Dead Letter Queue`, which can be set up for that lambda (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html). So you can monitor that queue to analyze the inputs that made the function to fail and take some action.

For logging, you can use `winston`(https://github.com/winstonjs/winston). Works fine with AWS lambdas.

Comment: DLQ is one of the ways I thought to implement. Do you have some automated processing of DLQ? And how do you use winston and in which cases is it better than CloudWatch logs?

Comment: The logging generated by winston is sent to CloudWatch, so you can use them together.

Answer (score 0):

In your lambda workflow I guess you have some kind of error handler function where is anything happens, It ends there. You can use that error handler to send you emails with the event and context inputs and other error thingy descriptions.

Also you can monitor lambdas via cloudfront, and create an alarm that sends you certain data if somethign went wrong.

Comment: I came from Ruby and I wanted to have some error handler that catches ANY error.
"I guess you have some kind of error handler function where is anything happens, It ends there." - I want to find the way how to put it in one place and forget about it.

Comment: What I do in node is concating promises. So you do something like `return Q.fcall(function1).then(function2).then(function3).catch(errorHandler).done()`. And error handler is a library I include in every lambda that does some processing (like rollbacks), send me an email, and returning error to front with some code, depending on which the error was.